# Error 1062. Duplicate entry in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1062

I have a MySQL table whose schema in which column 1 is primary key. 
I have a tsv file which I need to insert in this table. Now, the tsv has repetition of primary key hence when I try to insert it in MySQL table it gives an error

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '107664521128181760' for key
'PRIMARY'
```

Is there any way by which if the primary key value already exists, then it should ignore and move further for next insertion.

Comment: How are you inserting the records? Please accept an answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for **[INSERT IGNORE INTO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html)** command.

You can try like this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO yourtablename(col1,col2...)
values(val1,val2,...)
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you are importing the data.

If you are using LOAD DATA INFILE command then use IGNORE in command as:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'member.tsv'
IGNORE INTO TABLE tbl_member
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(name, age);
```

And if you are using sql having INSERT command then use INSERT IGNORE in INSERT command as:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO yourtablename(col1,col2...)
values(val1,val2,...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `REPLACE` query.

```
REPLACE INTO Users (Phone, Name, Email) VALUES ( Phone, Name, Email);
```